# kafka connect to s3 fails to start

Tags: amazon-s3, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect, apache-kafka-security

I'm trying to configure the kafka-connect to send my data from kafka to s3.
I'm newbie in aspect of kafka, and I'm trying to implement this flow without any ssl encryptions just to get the hang of it.

```
kafka version : 2.12-2.2.0
kafka-connect : 4.1.1 (https://api.hub.confluent.io/api/plugins/confluentinc/kafka-connect-s3/versions/4.1.1/archive)
```

In the `server.properties` file the only change that I did is setting the `advertised.listeners` to my ec2 IP:

```
advertised.listeners=PLAINTEXT://ip:9092
```

kafka-connect properties :

```
# Kafka broker IP addresses to connect to
bootstrap.servers=localhost:9092

# Path to directory containing the connector jar and dependencies
plugin.path=/root/kafka_2.12-2.2.0/plugins/

# Converters to use to convert keys and values
key.converter=org.apache.kafka.connect.storage.StringConverter
value.converter=org.apache.kafka.connect.storage.StringConverter

# The internal converters Kafka Connect uses for storing offset and configuration data
internal.key.converter=org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter
internal.value.converter=org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter
internal.key.converter.schemas.enable=false
internal.value.converter.schemas.enable=false
offset.storage.file.filename=/tmp/connect.offsets
security.protocol=SASL_PLAINTEXT
consumer.security.protocol=SASL_PLAINTEXT
```

my `s3-sink.properties` file :

```
name=s3.sink
connector.class=io.confluent.connect.s3.S3SinkConnector
tasks.max=1
topics=my_topic
s3.region=us-east-1
s3.bucket.name=my_bucket
s3.part.size=5242880
flush.size=3
storage.class=io.confluent.connect.s3.storage.S3Storage
format.class=io.confluent.connect.s3.format.json.JsonFormat
schema.generator.class=io.confluent.connect.storage.hive.schema.DefaultSchemaGenerator
partitioner.class=io.confluent.connect.storage.partitioner.DefaultPartitioner
schema.compatibility=NONE
```

I'm launcing kafka-connect with the following command :

```
connect-standalone.sh kafka-connect.properties s3-sink.properties
```

At first I got the following error :

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not find a 'KafkaClient' entry in the JAAS configuration. System property 'java.security.auth.login.config' is not set
```

From other posts I saw that I need to create a jaas config file so that what I did :

```
cat config/kafka_server_jass.conf
KafkaClient {
org.apache.kafka.common.security.plain.PlainLoginModule required
username="userName"
serviceName="kafka"
password="password";
};
```

and :

```
export KAFKA_OPTS="-Djava.security.auth.login.config=/root/kafka_2.12-2.2.0/config/kafka_server_jass.conf"
```

Now I'm getting the following error :

```
Caused by: org.apache.kafka.common.errors.SaslAuthenticationException: Failed to configure SaslClientAuthenticator
Caused by: org.apache.kafka.common.KafkaException: Principal could not be determined from Subject, this may be a transient failure due to Kerberos re-login
```

help  :)

Answer (score 0):

You might also need to define `principal` and `keytab` inside your jaas configuration:

```
KafkaClient {
  org.apache.kafka.common.security.plain.PlainLoginModule required
  username="userName" 
  serviceName="kafka"
  password="password";
  useKeyTab=true
  keyTab="/etc/security/keytabs/kafka_server.keytab"
  principal="kafka/kafka1.hostname.com@EXAMPLE.COM";
};
```

Comment: ahm does the keytab file should contain anything ? or it is fine if its empty ?

Comment: @JeyJ Obviously it shouldn't be empty. A keytab is a file that  contains pairs of Kerberos principals and encrypted keys. For more details refer to this question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43863275/what-is-a-keytab-exactly

Comment: So I need it even if I dont use kerberos ? I just want to have a non encrypted stream of data from kafka to s3..