# Kerberos on Windows Server out of domain

Tags: windows, kerberos

I want to implement kerberos authentication for a software where both the server and the clients run on Windows and are implemented in C++.
When both, the clients and the server are on the same Windows domain it is straight forward to use SSPI and I assume this will work also for cross-realm environments.

When for any reason the server cannot be member of the domain this straigth forward approach will not work.
How is it possible to achieve Kerberos authentiaction against a server that is not member of the domain?

If my research is correct java applications or linux use a [keytab file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43863275/what-is-a-keytab-exactly) instead of implicitly retrieving the key from AD. Apparently SSPI does not support keytab files. Is there a way to use keytab files in this scenario?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SSPI does not "retrieve the key from AD" – the service key is always stored locally, but with SSPI it's the *machine account password* which was generated during AD join process (and uploaded to AD rather than retrieved from) that acts in place of the keytab. Windows stores the machine password in LSA and derives the key from it in memory, but it has the same purpose as a keytab file.

There *may* be a way to store a machine password in a non-AD machine (using ksetup.exe), but it is very much a system-wide change – it seems to make certain parts of the Windows login process function as if the system was domain-joined – so I would **not** recommend doing so, except in a test VM.

Instead, you can use another Kerberos implementation – **[MIT Kerberos](https://web.mit.edu/kerberos/)** and **[Heimdal](https://github.com/heimdal/)** are the two major non-AD Kerberos implementations that come in the form of C libraries (both are Windows-compatible, though their focus is on Linux/Unix-like systems). Both libraries provide the GSSAPI interface, which is similar to Windows SSPI, and both use keytab files for service credentials.

For C#, [Kerberos.NET](https://github.com/dotnet/Kerberos.NET) is available. For Rust, [sspi-rs](https://github.com/Devolutions/sspi-rs) seems to be in active development (it isn't just a binding to Windows SSPI but a standalone implementation as well). Java of course has its own Kerberos implementation built-in [as part of JAAS](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/security/single-sign-using-kerberos-java1.htm#JSSEC-GUID-D4230975-A28B-4532-B1DD-3C7219A4867F) although [Apache Kerby](https://directory.apache.org/kerby/) exists as well.

Most of those implementations support the same keytab format because they mimic MIT Kerberos to some extent (which was the original Kerberos 5 implementation).

Both MIT Krb5 and Heimdal include not just a library but a KDC service as well, though that part won't run on Windows. (Kerby and Kerberos.NET *could* also be used to build minimal KDCs.)

---

The above is more important for servers; however, a *client* can use SSPI to authenticate to Kerberos services without any requirement to be a domain member.

For realms that are AD-based (regardless of the specific server being domain-joined or not), it is enough to provide a UPN-format username (in the form of `user@domain`) and a password to SSPI; it will automatically discover KDCs and obtain tickets.

The same works for Kerberos realms that are not AD-based as long as the realm is marked as a "MIT realm" either via registry or using `ksetup /AddRealmFlags`. (The principal `user@REALM` needs to be specified as username in this case.) Unlike the earlier mentioned case, this ksetup.exe usage seems to have no negative side effects.